# Angularjs $httpd assign variable onSuccess to $scope empty

Tags: http, angularjs, controller

I have a controller:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http,) {

    $scope.saveit = function () {
        $scope.key = '';
        $http.get('/getHash',{"key": $scope.key})
        .success(function(response, status, headers, config){
            $scope.key = response.key;
        });
    }

    console.log ($scope.key) // key is empty
}
```

Why is at the end `$scope.key` empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be set until you actually call `saveit()`, which you won't have done yet when your log statement is executed. You've *defined* a function that sets `key`, but you haven't *invoked* it.

Comment: sorry I forgot this to write, the form calls it on submit `<form ng-controller="UgeistCtrl" ng-submit="saveit()">`

Comment: Then where in your code *is* the `console.log($scope.key)` call? Regardless of when `saveit` is called, `key` won't yet have been set at the particular point in space and time where/when the controller is being defined. Did you mean to log it *inside* the HTTP `success` function instead?

Comment: ahhh you are right, it's a time problem! but how can i access $scope.key and make sure it's set?

Comment: Do it from inside the `success` function.